# Energy estimates for heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, parabolic-pde

Let $ \Omega $ be a $ C^1 $ bounded domain and $ T $ a positive number. Assume that $ v $ is a weak solution for the heat equation
\begin{eqnarray}
\left\{\begin{matrix}
\partial_tv-\Delta v=0&\text{in}&\Omega\times(0,T),\\
v=g&\text{on}&\partial\Omega\times(0,T),\\
v=0&\text{on}&\Omega\times\left\{0\right\},
\end{matrix}\right.
\end{eqnarray}
where $ g $ is in some function spaces to be determined. I want to get the energy-type estimates for the equation, for example, I want to obtain the boundedness for
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{0}^T\int_{\Omega}|\nabla v|^2dxdt
\end{eqnarray}
by some norm of $ g $. In the famous book written by Evans, I know already the answer in the case $ g=0 $. However, I am unable to deal with the case that $ g $ does not vanish. My question can be stated as follows:

> (1) What space should I choose for $ g $ such that the energy-type
> estimate exists?

> (2) How to obtain the energy-type estimate above?

Comment: Have you tried multiplying the PDE by $v$ and integrating by parts over the domain?

Comment: @mattos, I have tried for this, but I do not know how to deal with the term $ \int_{\partial\Omega}|\frac{\partial v}{\partial n}|^2dS $.